# Step by step running apache Nutch 2.2.1

Tags: nutch

I have config plugin.folders in nutch-default.xml but when I run Nutch via Eclipse & Netbeans,

```
Main class: org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob
Arguments: /MY_DATA_SOURCE/HR_PROJECTS/JSearch/Apache_Nutch/RELEASE/release-2.2.1/urls
VM Options: -Dhadoop.log.dir=logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log
```

THe errors like below:

```
cd /MY_DATA_SOURCE/HR_PROJECTS/JSearch/Apache_Nutch/RELEASE/release-2.2.1; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" "-Dexec.args=-Dhadoop.log.dir=logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -classpath %classpath org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob /MY_DATA_SOURCE/HR_PROJECTS/JSearch/Apache_Nutch/RELEASE/release-2.2.1/urls" -Dexec.executable=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Apache Nutch 2.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[resources:resources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using platform encoding (US-ASCII actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
skip non existing resourceDirectory /MY_DATA_SOURCE/HR_PROJECTS/JSearch/Apache_Nutch/RELEASE/release-2.2.1/src/main/resources

[compiler:compile]
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[exec:exec]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/hung/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/hung/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.6.1/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/hung/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.1/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
13/07/06 08:55:18 INFO crawl.InjectorJob: InjectorJob: starting at 2013-07-06 08:55:18
13/07/06 08:55:18 INFO crawl.InjectorJob: InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: /MY_DATA_SOURCE/HR_PROJECTS/JSearch/Apache_Nutch/RELEASE/release-2.2.1/urls
2013-07-06 08:55:18.420 java[1206:1c03] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
13/07/06 08:55:18 WARN store.DataStoreFactory: gora.properties not found, properties will be empty.
13/07/06 08:55:18 WARN store.DataStoreFactory: gora.properties not found, properties will be empty.
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO crawl.InjectorJob: InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore as the Gora storage class.
13/07/06 08:55:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/07/06 08:55:19 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/07/06 08:55:19 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local226390157_0001
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local226390157_0001_m_000000_0
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/MY_DATA_SOURCE/HR_PROJECTS/JSearch/Apache_Nutch/RELEASE/release-2.2.1/urls/seed.txt:0+20
13/07/06 08:55:19 WARN store.DataStoreFactory: gora.properties not found, properties will be empty.
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO mapreduce.GoraRecordWriter: gora.buffer.write.limit = 10000
13/07/06 08:55:19 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
13/07/06 08:55:19 WARN mapred.FileOutputCommitter: Output path is null in cleanup
13/07/06 08:55:19 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local226390157_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: plugin.folders is not defined
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: plugin.folders is not defined
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginManifestParser.parsePluginFolder(PluginManifestParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRepository.<init>(PluginRepository.java:69)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.PluginRepository.get(PluginRepository.java:97)
    at org.apache.nutch.net.URLNormalizers.<init>(URLNormalizers.java:117)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob$UrlMapper.setup(InjectorJob.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
13/07/06 08:55:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/07/06 08:55:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local226390157_0001
13/07/06 08:55:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
13/07/06 08:55:20 ERROR crawl.InjectorJob: InjectorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=inject /MY_DATA_SOURCE/HR_PROJECTS/JSearch/Apache_Nutch/RELEASE/release-2.2.1/urls, jobid=job_local226390157_0001
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:233)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 6.572s
Finished at: Sat Jul 06 08:55:20 ICT 2013
Final Memory: 11M/236M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project nutch: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit value: 255) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: How could you run nutch 2.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly indicates the problem (and where to look for a solution):

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/hung/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/hung/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.6.1/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/hung/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.1/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Comment: How could i run the apache nutch 2.2.1 src

Comment: @jackyesind you don't run apache nutch 2.2.1 source but rather you compile it using ant, go the directory that contains the source and run the command "ant runtime" when compilation finish you have a directory structure that looks like "nutch-src/runtime/local/bin" inside this path you will see the binaries that you need to execute.